# How to insert many entries in one database field

Tags: database, database-design

I have a Java webproject with servlets, jsp, java and so on. There I have many projects inside, which I can choose in a combobox like this:

```
Project [Combobox]    

Priority[Combobox]     Stage[Combobox]
```

For each project I can select other values in the combobox Priority and Stage. 
So we can say, that the values in priority and stage are always in relation with the chosen project.

In the database I have tables like this:

```
Table project:
projectid    
projectname

Table priority
id 
priorityname 
projectname
```

---

Know if i have the value prio1 for the priority and i want to give this value Project 1 and Project 2, i have to do two entries in the database in the table priority: like this

```
id priorityname projectname
1  prio1        project1 
1  prio1        project2
```

But i want to do only one entrie the database: So my idea in the database was like this:

```
id priorityname projectname
1  prio1        project1,project2
```

I don't have much experience in this subject. So I wanted to tell you this, maybe my idea isn't good and I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: I'd stick with your existing design and keep two rows. Storing multiple data items in a single column can quickly turn into a nightmare once you need to write new queries, and almost always means that no amount of indexing can help speed up your queries.

Comment: If you really, really want to de-normalize the model use an array of strings instead of a comma separated list if your DBMS supports array data types.

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert multiple values in one database-field.

Depending on your used Database there should be different ways to reach your goal.
Try using *Foreign Keys* if your Database supports them (e.g. `MySQL InnoDB` databases do).

With *foreign Keys* you'd need to point from your `Project` table entries to a `Priority` entry.
You then can do a `SELECT` query, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects, 
     priorities 
WHERE projects.proj_priority = priorities.prio_id 
  AND priorities.prio_name = "prio1"
```

(assuming)

The tables would look like this:

```
projects (proj_id, proj_name, proj_priority)
priorities (prio_id, prio_name)
```

where `proj_id` and `prio_id` are the primary keys and `proj_priority` is the foreign key.